# jQuery find('img').attr('src') does not work

Tags: jquery

The following code will not work:

`find('img').attr('src')`

I want hover on aside area and image change on/off.

**HTML**

```
<aside style="width:200px;height:300px;text-align:center;">
  <img class="img" src="imgs/photo_off.png" alt="" >
</aside>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("aside").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr('src') = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace("_off", "_on");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr('src') = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace("_on", "_off");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't assign a value to a function call statement like that. It should thrown an error like

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Use the setter version of [.attr(name, value)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value)

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace("_off", "_on"));
```

or [.attr(name, callback)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

```
$("aside").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
        return src.replace("_off", "_on");
    })
}, function () {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
        return src.replace("_on", "_off");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('img')[0].src = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace("_off", "_on");
```